# Removed bracketed numbers at the end in Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove **ONLY** the bracketed numbers at the end of a line.  For example

**Before**

```
Hello World (5)
My (12) is (5923)
```

**After**

```
Hello World
My (12) is
```

I've managed to get to the following Regex, however it removes the first instance of a bracketed number rather than the last:

```
\s*\([^a-zA-Z)]*\)
```

Any suggestions on how I can get it to do as per the above.  It needs to only remove the bracketed numbers (and space before them) at the end

Comment: any preference to programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
\s*\(\d+\)$
```

`$` - anchor which points to the end of the string

[https://regex101.com/r/ZnTuKd/21](https://regex101.com/r/ZnTuKd/2)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect